# Does RecycledViewPool works fine when I set it into different RecyclerView in different Activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When we use RecyclerView in RecyclerView, like Google play App, we can set same RecycleredViewPool to both outer and inner RecyclerView.

What if two RecyclerView in different Activities? Is RecycledViewPool still works fine? These two views have the same adapter.

I had tried, and onCreateView has called in the second activity, but I think that because I miss something.

The reason of I doing this is for performance. Every time onCreateView called, lots of time will cost, because LayoutInflater parse xml.

Otherwise, leave this question on the other side, how to build a high performance list page, just like Youtube, their FPS is very high.

Comment: just don't touch recycler pool, leave it as is

Comment: @Eugene It's for performance, any item type cost lots of time when onCreateViewHolder called,because LayoutInflater need parse XML.

Comment: are you measured it already? how much mills it costs?

Comment: Our app have lots of item type. Most item cost 40ms. and the onBindViewHolder takes 4 or 6 ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should not use RecycledViewPool across multiple Activities**.
The Views inside have a reference to their host Context and wouldn't work properly when being used in a different Context from where they where created.
Additionally there would be a memory leak by keeping both Activities alive, since the pool references the views, referencing the Activities.

To accomplish this in the first place you might have a static reference to the RecycledViewPool. This should be a dead giveaway that it might not be a good idea as you are holding static references to Views, and thus indirectly to their Contexts.

---

TL;DR new Activity means new View pool.

Comment: Oh,It's a obvious point I missed. How about Framgent, looks like same as Activity? So,it's only case we can use in RecyclerView in RecyclerView ?

Comment: Using across Fragments (within the same Activity) should be fine. The best case for reusing the pool is when you have multiple RecyclerViews *with the save viewTypes*. So not the outer and inner recyclers (as they would have different child views) but the multiple inner recyclers (which would have the same type of children).